# How to bulk add vast amounts of posts

Tags: posts, bulk-import

I'm looking for a way to automatically add a large number of example posts to a WordPress blog for testing purposes.

I have the requirement to test a bulk process on 15,000 English blog posts (one or two paragraphs of text and nonsensical titles will do). As you can imagine, getting this volume of test content populated isn't something one would like to do by hand!

Comment: Would all the data have to be different, such as some containing media, some containing lists etc? Also, please edit your post to show what you have tried, and whether it has been successful.

Comment: Actually I only need a paragraph or two worth of English sentences in each. Could be random, could be the same.

Comment: I would reckon that a PHP FOR or WHILE loop with a connection to the post DB of Wordpress would achieve this. So you would increment the loop, and every time it goes up one, insert a random sentence of your choosing into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Right click on [this link](https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xml) and save the XML full of dummy content provided by WordPress
2. In the sample data, you can remove the unwanted data such as pages, comments, categories, etc.
3. Go to Tools > Import in the admin panel
4. Install the "WordPress" importer from the list
5. Activate & Run Importer
6. Upload the XML file
7. Map the authors in this export file to users of your choosing
8. WordPress will then import each of the posts

If this doesn't satisfy, I'd recommend looking into [plugins that generate dummy content](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/dummy-content) to your expectations

Comment: Hmm...FakerPress looks very useful. However, it generates randomized lorem ipsum text. I require random English sentences. (Sorry for not stating this properly in my original post.) Any idea how one could attain that goal?

Comment: @player.mdl Found some sample data that may be useful, update my answer.